# What is [0] at the end of a JavaScript statement?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
var a = element.getElementsByTagName( 'div' ) [0];
```

I know that it returns an HTMLCollection, but what does [0] mean at the end of it?

Comment: In programming the first item in a list is usually at index 0. Programmers usually like to start counting at 0 rather than 1 :-)

Answer (score 5):

`getElementsByTagName` returns *an array like object* instead of a single element. So `[0]` selects the first element of the array.

So its like

```
var i,n;
var alldivs = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' );

//use array length to get number of matched elements
console.log("there are "+alldivs.length+" divs on the page");

//loop through each element in array
for(i=0,n=alldivs.length; i<n; i++) {
    console.log(alldivs[i]); 
}
```

Here is [**a sample fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2wdtexkx/2/).

#### note:

Here as spender points out, `alldivs` is not exactly an array. Means if you do

```
console.log(alldivs instanceof Array);//false
console.log([] instanceof Array);//true
```

So it means it is an [**`html collection`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which could be looped over like arrays and its an array like object. But you cannot treat it like an exact array by using normal functions available on `Array.prototype` like `push()`,`pop()`,`forEach` etc.

Comment: yes you are right. `alldivs instanceof Array` will give false.